# Cryptogen tool not found. Hyperledger fabric installation in Windows 10

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I followed the Hyperledger fabric [documentation](https://hyperledgerfabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html) to install and configure it in Windows 10. However when I run the command - ".`/byfn.sh -m generate`" for first-network sample application, I get the following error,

[image]
I have gone thru all StackOverflow questions regarding this and made sure following steps are done,

1. Have set the $PATH variable correctly to include bin folder.
2. Have downloaded the platform-specific binary and my bin folder looks like this,

[image]

I have doubts about following steps,

1. I have installed Docker for Windows and was able to verify the docker installation by running hello-world image in Docker. However, I have not shared any of my local drives in Docker. Not sure whether this is the cause of this error.

Please note that this is my first question in StackOverflow. Forgive me for any mistakes/redundancies. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making sure that you run the script to download / install the binaries and images from within the fabric-samples directory.

Answer (score 0):

The $Path is exported every time you run the byfn.sh script, confirm that the path configuration in the byfn.sh is correct and points to your correct bin location

```
# prepending $PWD/../bin to PATH to ensure we are picking up the correct binaries
# this may be commented out to resolve installed version of tools if desired
export PATH=${PWD}/../../bin:${PWD}:$PATH
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=${PWD}
```